# How to save location of an element in JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
dummy = {
    "fieldone": {
        "fieldtwo": {
            "yetanother": {
                "another-nested-one": "the-deepest-nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to access a particular element I would do this:

```
s = dummy["fieldone"]["fieldtwo"]
print(s)

{'yetanother': {'another-nested-one': 'the-deepest-nested'}}
```

But my element is deeply nested (a lot more than the example of course), so I would like to save the *path* to the element this way:

```
path = ["fieldone"]["fieldtwo"]
test = dummy.get(path)
# or dummy[path]
# or dummy.path
print(test)
```

When I run this I receive the following message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-57cff8dffc3a> in <module>
----> 1 path = ["fieldone"]["fieldtwo"]
      2 test = dummy[path]
      3 print(test)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Is there any way to save the location of the elements and retrieve them later this way? I could do it by an endless chain like:

```
my_element = dummy["level_one"]["level_two"]["level_three"]
```

But I wonder if there is a more elegant way of achieving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def getFromDict(dict, list):
     return reduce(operator.getitem, list, dict)
```

In particular, with your input:

```
path = ["fieldone", "fieldtwo"]
print(getFromDict(dummy, path))

#output: {'yetanother': {'another-nested-one': 'the-deepest-nested'}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ElidorDD

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
def get_by_path(my_dict, path):
    if len(path) == 1:
        return my_dict[path[0]]

    return get_by_path(my_dict[path[0]], path[1:])


dummy = {
    "fieldone": {
        "fieldtwo": {
            "yetanother": {
                "another-nested-one": "the-deepest-nested"
            }
        }
    }
}

my_path = ("fieldone", "fieldtwo")


print(get_by_path(dummy , my_path))
```

output:

```
{'yetanother': {'another-nested-one': 'the-deepest-nested'}}
```